Continue TensorBoard Logging from a Previous Timestep When Resuming Training with Stable Baselines3
I am working with a reinforcement learning model using Stable Baselines3, specifically a PPO model. I train my model for a certain number of timesteps, let's say 500, using the following code:
log_dir='./logging_directory/'
model = PPO_model("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_dir)
model.learn(total_timesteps=500, callback=[customMetricsLogger])

The model is saved to a zip folder using the customMetricsLogger callback. Also, the logged variables are saved in ./logging_directory/PPO_1.
Now I want to load the model and continue training. However, I'm facing an issue with TensorBoard logging.
When I resume training and specify the same logging directory that I used in the initial training session, TensorBoard does not continue logging in the same file. Instead, it creates a new directory (e.g., 'PPO_2') and starts logging from timestep 0 again. Here is how I load the model and specify the logging directory:
model = PPO_model.load(model_path, env=env, tensorboard_log=log_dir)

My goal is to continue logging in the same 'PPO_1' directory and have the logs display a continuous line in TensorBoard, starting from the last timestep of the previous training phase when I run tensorboard --logdir .. Or if having the same line is not possible, at least have the new line start from 500. Is it possible to setup the number of timesteps the model already trained for tensorboard?
